# Configuring backup drives for Alwayson

Tags: backup, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

I have an alwayson cluster which was already built when I joined the company. Both the nodes Have Data and log drives but no dedicated Backup drives. The Veeam application which resides in this cluster is not growing much in terms of database size and is being backed up to the data drive as of now.

We are planning to add two more applications to this cluster. I am thinking to ask for a dedicated backup drive for this. My question is does this 2 node setup require 2 backup drives? One for secondary and one for primary? Please clarify

Thanks!

Comment: This is somewhat ambiguous. Is this a FCI (Failover Cluster Instance) or are you using AGs (Availability Groups)? The conflating terms being used here make it difficult to provide a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ... is being backed up to the data drive as of now.

So, what happens when you lose a node? What would happen if that server crashed and burned or you lost the data drive? Now you've lost the database backups...

> My question is does this 2 node setup require 2 backup drives? One for secondary and one for primary? Please clarify

The best option would be to have an SMB 3.x share to which these backups are sent. You could also tie into a 3rd party backup software like Commvault, netbackup, etc., by writing your backup process to hit local disk then copy to the 3rd party service/appliance.

The reason is that the AG could be primary on, potentially, any node. If we're backing up to local disk, the backups could be spread across many nodes. This means we might not be able to have an entire backup chain when it comes time for a disaster.

Comment: Can I request for a LUN and ask the storage team to provision a backup drive on each of the node? Would that be helpful? Please suggest.

Comment: Sean's first statement should be your wake up call.  You a lose a node, you lose your backups, you lose your data.  We like using a network share to put all of our production backups on that is isolated from the servers themselves.  You do NOT want to lose those backups in the event of an emergency,  You're only as good as your last tested backup.

Comment: Will do thanks. Will request for a file share first where the databases can be stored before starting the project. Thanks so much for the help and suggestions!